# Is it possible to specify two different values for font-display when requesting multiple fonts from Google Fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

I used to use

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700|Material+Icons">`

But have recently learnt of font-display.

What I'd like to do, is

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700|Material+Icons&amp;display=fallback|block">`

But it doesn't seem to work, so instead I'm having to add an extra HTTP request:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&amp;display=fallback">'`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons&amp;display=block">'`

Is that the best I can do, or is there an (as far as I can see) undocumented trick?